# Noun for a man who is turned down for a date regularly

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a noun to describe a man who is unsuccessful with women and turned down for a date regularly. Women don't see him as a lover and don't want to engage in sexual relations with him because he is untidy in dress and appearance. He is unappealing and unattractive because of unwashed hair, overweight, smelly socks and yellow underarm stains on his clothes.
The example:

> A: He asks random girls out on a date. They always reject him.
>
> B:  You know he is such a ____

Comment: I'm thinking "male", but that's usually treated as an adjective.

Comment: There's always several reasons, you need to describe the man in question. "Women do not want to date him for some reason", is too little to go on. Is he extremely *shy*, *timid*, *inexperienced*, *arrogant*, *cocky*, is he *all hat and no cattle* etc. etc.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A I described a man in question. Not that this man is shy or arrogant. As a lover he is uninteresting to women.

Comment: What's the context where you want to use this? An essay about the emasculation of the modern male? A locker room juvenile trash talk battle? A Reddit discussion on SWJs?

Comment: @Mitch adult talks & gossip in a locker room.

Comment: Sorry, but I knew the hours were counted for this question. The question can be reopened if you provide a sentence where the word you are looking for would fit in. If five users vote to reopen the question then other people can submit their suggestions.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Okay. My question should be reworded to fit the rules. I've read through the rules in the help center. Here's my edited question.

Comment: One vote to reopen by me, four more to go. You might need to wait a while, I'm afraid. But it's a good question now, well done! @Mitch how about casting a vote to reopen this question, it's much improved.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A I remember that you mentioned the word "a turn-off". I've looked it up in a dictionary, and I think this is a suitable word. :)

Comment: [a turn-off](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/turn-off?q=turn+off) A person or thing that causes someone to feel bored, disgusted, or sexually repelled. @Mari-Lou

Comment: Typical, I deleted that comment. Something about yellow sweat stains on shirts being a right turn off. The phrase: "He is  a real turn-off" works!

Comment: The adjectives "**unattractive**" or "**unappealing**" can fit. ==> *You know, he is such an unattractive guy*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I find this way too broad and tendentious. There are many words that would be appropriate but not specifically limited to this situation. (I think 'loser' is actually the 'right' word.) But since you ask I'll vote to reopen. If it attracts junk answers (as I suspect it might) I'll be annoyed.

Answer (score 1):

You may call them *loser*, or maybe *outcast*, *undesirable*, *persona non grata* or *pariah* depending on the actual case.

Comment: I think the first two seem right on the money, but I'm not so sure about the other three. (Not my downvote, btw.)

Comment: @J.R. please cast a vote and reopen the question. It deserves a fighting chance.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I'll keep my eye on the question. If the O.P. can explain why an obvious choice like "loser" or "misfit" won't work, and therefore put a little more focus into the question, I'll cast my vote. I'd also want to know: are we looking for a word that women might use to describe this fellow, or men? Women might call him a _pest_, but men might call him a _dweeb_.

Comment: @J.R. well I agree *loser* is probably the best bet, but if he is asking it's because he doesn't know a suitable word, and that's why users should explain what these terms mean, especially to a non native speaker. I am now going to check what *dweeb* means, I've heard it, but I don't know how to use it! EDIT *dweeb* is very good!

Comment: This question probably would not have gotten closed on [ell.se]. There, we expect and accept that O.P.'s might not know the "obvious" word for something. I'm not sure if ELU, though, is the right exchange to ask for synonyms for _loser_, which is what this question seems to be asking.

Comment: I down voted this answer because it seemed completely inappropriate to suggest words like _loser_, the way the question was worded when I voted. The question has now been fundamentally altered and focuses on a completely different thing, and this answer is now much more appropriate, so I've undownvoted.

Answer (score 1):

The conclusion that

> Women do not want to date him for some reason

Does not follow from the statement that

> reason is ... in his inability to get along with woman

I presume what you want is someone who is seeking a romantic relationship with a woman but is unable to do so because he thinks that woman want to date him for no reason, but at the same time it is because he is oblivious of the fact that he is socially incompatible with them. Then, based on this, I cannot help you further other than possibly clarify what you mean, although the word *insular* comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED
 A man who fails to attract a potential romantic partner might be someone who *lacks sex appeal*. If he doesn't wear the right clothes, seems [gauche](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gauche?topic=inability-and-awkwardness) or clumsy, and fails to follow the most basic standard of personal hygiene he is, without doubt, **undesirable**. A  man who is uninteresting to talk to, who doesn't *[fit in](http://www.succeedsocially.com/fittingin)* or comply with today's *aesthetic canons* of male beauty, might be termed an **outsider**.  The Free Dictionary defines it as someone  “*[who is excluded from or does not belong to a group, association, or set](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/outsider).*”

Not a noun, but an adjective which is pretty much in vogue recently, is **undateable**, it describes any person who cannot find a long term partner or ‘date’. In British English we have the noun **undateables**, which also happens to be the name of a Channel 4 TV documentary.

The noun **saddo** (BrEng) seems appropriate, the epithet is usually reserved for men who have no friends and are socially inept in public. *[Saddos](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/saddo)*, like *undateables*  have great difficulty in finding dates.

Finally, someone whose manners, behaviour or physical appearance is unappealing to the opposite sex is said to be a **turn-off**, this is a gender neutral noun, and can be applied to anyone. Oxford Dictionaries cites

> <sub><sup>usually in singular. INFORMAL</sup></sub> A person or thing that causes someone to feel bored, disgusted, or sexually repelled: *he smelled of carbolic soap, a dreadful turn-off* [and]
>   *[His crooked yellow teeth are a complete turn-off](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/turn-off)*